# PowerBI in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, json, powerbi

Has anybody of you experience with integrating PowerBI Dashboards/Tiles into SharePoint ?

For my case I am searching a solution, where I can get Dashboards/Tiles via JSON File. Iframe is not a solution, cause there will be an error regarding authentication.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is PowerBI is available in  SP 2013 onpremises? i heard its available on office 365 only - SPO

Comment: As far as I know its only available with office 365 - According to this, I am searching a solution to integrate it to SharePoint...

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the type of dashboard you need? If you are going to get the data from JSON where does SharePoint comes in?  PowerBI is great tool for Dashboard, I have used it for our file share analysis but I exported data from excel/csv file.

Comment: Have a look at this.  I just came across this.  http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2016/2/publish-power-bi-report-to-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint BI for the same, which is also very powerful and can serve your requirement of dash board.

Below Link will give you basic idea on the same.

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/what-you-need-know-about-bi-sharepoint-2013

Also check the link below to differentiate between Power BI and SharePoint BI

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2014/5/26/differences-between-power-bi-and-sharepoint-bi

Comment: Thanks for your input - but for my case / requirement, i have to integrate power bi into SharePoint...

Comment: Your environment is On Premise?
You can check this tutorial on YouTube by BCG Systems.. It may help you..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Yk0_ctoGn8
I have done implementation of BI in SharePoint On premise and it is quite similar to Power BI dashboard what you are asking for....

I would suggest just give it a try may suffice your requirement