# Auto updating chart from a list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, chart, bi

I have a SharePoint list and I want to show it in a tabular table in home page of SharePoint and data be online in which by changing data in the list the data of the table change automatically. What can I do?

Comment: Pls mention your question clearly. Your question reads you need a chart and description reads you need a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Chart Webpart.

***Chart Webpart enables users to visualize numerical data and get business insights such as trends at a glance***

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/09/12/chart-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint BI for the same, which is also very powerful and can serve your requirement of dash board. Data would refresh automatically and also manual refresh option is available.

Below Link will give you basic idea on the same.

[blog link 1](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/what-you-need-know-about-bi-sharepoint-2013)

Also check the link below to differentiate between Power BI and SharePoint BI

[blog link 2](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2014/5/26/differences-between-power-bi-and-sharepoint-bi)

Reference: [PowerBI Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171112/powerbi-in-sharepoint-2013/171212#171212)

SharePoint Power BI requires enterprise version of SharePoint. So thats one of the limitation I know of.

You can also go with Scripting approach to create chart and Auto Refresh same using external api and Rest API to fetch data.

Chart Options:

- [google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- [google link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpqNrgyODMAhVFvY8KHZ6hAF8QFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.highcharts.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNErrb7ECcVdKXa5navoW71_DlvI1w)
- [Chartis](http://www.chartjs.org/)

You can use Rest API or JSOM approach to fetch data from list and then auto refresh same using window.setTimeout.

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSRS reporting services available, you can create a list data source and put a chart on the report connected to the data source. This would be simple, quick and out-of-the-box with no code. You can set the refresh options on the data source.